# Error to connect mongos when trying to create replicated sharded cluster

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding, load-balancing

I'm trying to create an replicated sharded cluster in mongodb. Initially I've created two shards and there are a replica set with three members in each shard. And all the shards and replicasets run in a single machine. I followed

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/
```

to deploy this structure and that worked perfectly.

But as I'm running my mongodb in an AWS instance for a business application and I'm connecting my node.js server with the database, I want to load balance the database within multiple aws instance so that the database works fine even in huge traffic load and even if one instance becomes unhealthy or unavailable, I'll be able to access the database from the replicaset running in other instances.

Depending on the suggestions of different users in my previous question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671205/mongodb-load-balancing-in-multiple-aws-instances
```

I'm trying to divide the database in shards and each shard will have a replicaSet with 3 or more members running in separate aws instances.
To create this structure, I tried to deploy it locally at first.

I've two replicasets firstset & secondset

The firstset has three members 192.168.1.10:27018(Primary), 192.168.1.11.27018(Secondary) & 192.168.1.9:27018(arbiter)

And the secondset has three members 192.168.1.6:27019(Primary), 192.168.1.9:27019(Secondary) & 192.169.1.11:27019(arbiter)

To create the firstset replica I've written

```
mongod --dbpath /replica-data --port 27018 --replSet firstset --oplogSize 10
```

in 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11 & 192.168.1.9

Then to initiate the replica set I've written

```
mongo --port 27018
```

in 192.168.1.10 and then,

```
use admin

db.runCommand({
 "replSetInitiate": {
    "_id": "firstset",
    "members": [{
         "_id": 1,
         "host": "192.168.1.10:27018",
         "priority": 10
         }, {
         "_id": 2,
         "host": "192.168.1.11:27018",
         "priority": 2
         }, {
         "_id": 3,
         "host": "192.168.1.9:27018",
         "priority": 1,
         "arbiterOnly": true
         }]
         }
    });
```

I've created the secondset replica is similar way and it worked.

Then I tried to create three configsvrs in three separate machine so that even if one machine shuts down the other configsvrs will be running. The configsvs will run in 192.168.1.10:27020, 192.168.1.11:27020 & 192.168.1.6:27020

So I've written

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /shard-data -port 27020
```

in 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11 & 192.168.1.6.

Then I tried to run the mongos in 192.168.1.10 in 27030 port with the three running configdb. So, I've written

```
mongos --configdb 192.168.1.10:27020,192.168.1.11:27020,192.168.1.6:27020 --port 27030 --chunkSize 1
```

Then I got in mongos log:

```
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] MongoS version 2.6.3 starting:     pid=4195 port=27030 64-bit host=innofied-lappy (--help for usage)
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] db version v2.6.3
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] git version: 255f67a66f9603c59380b2a389e386910bbb52cb
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] build info: Linux build12.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-07-11T13:52:34.502+0530 [mongosMain] options: { net: { port: 27030 }, sharding: { chunkSize: 1, configDB: "192.168.1.10:27020,192.168.1.7:27020,192.168.1.8:27020" } }
2014-07-11T13:52:34.518+0530 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.1.10:27020]
2014-07-11T13:52:34.524+0530 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.1.7:27020]
2014-07-11T13:52:34.527+0530 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.1.8:27020]
2014-07-11T13:52:34.618+0530 [mongosMain] scoped connection to 192.168.1.10:27020,192.168.1.7:27020,192.168.1.8:27020 not being returned to the pool
2014-07-11T13:52:45.956+0530 [mongosMain] waited 11s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-07-11T13:52:57.613+0530 [mongosMain] waited 22s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
```

And also could not found any mongos process at the specific port.
So, when I run

```
mongo --port 27030
```

it's showing me

```
errno:111 conncetion refused.
```

But previously it working perfectly when I was testing it in a single machine.

Please help me why I'm getting this error and how to solve it.

Comment: Your log says that the mongos is running on port 27030, not 27017 - are you connecting to the right port?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have connected on port 27030. At first I test on 27017. So, copy it from there and forgot to edit. I faced the same problem in both cases.

Comment: This is very likely an issue with security groups, something not allowing the connection on that port like bindIP, or similar then, since you are getting connection refused.  I could try to replicate, but I'd need to know what AMI you are using (and any changes you might have made to the security group) to be sure.  As an immediate test, try specifying the full host:port to make sure you use the loopback interface: `mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27030`

Comment: I did not made any changes in security groups.
`mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27030` will not work as no process is running on 27030 port(I have checked the running process list in `sudo netstat -nltp`).

Comment: The point was to try the full host:port version to connect rather than having the OS resolve localhost - just run it on whatever port you are actually running a mongos/mongod process on instead.  You also have not mentioned the AMI you are using, what version of MongoDB you are using yet - if you could (and mention how you got the MongoDB binaries too - straight download, package install?) that would be great

Comment: Version of my mongodb is 2.6.3 and I installed this following [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) link. I didn't put it in amazon. While I'm testing this in local machines connected in lan got this error.

Comment: I also tried `mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27030`. But got the same error.

Comment: Have you read this post

[Connection refused to MongoDB errno 111][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899849/connection-refused-to-mongodb-errno-111